# Groupby first by a conditional value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, like this:

| ID | date | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 2022-01-01 | 0 |
| 10 | 2022-01-02 | 0 |
| 10 | 2022-01-03 | 1 |
| 10 | 2022-01-04 | 1 |
| 10 | 2022-01-05 | 1 |
| 23 | 2022-02-02 | 0 |
| 23 | 2022-02-03 | 0 |
| 23 | 2022-02-04 | 1 |
| 23 | 2022-02-05 | 1 |
| 23 | 2022-02-06 | 1 |

I would like to group per ID and the first date on status is equal 1.

Expected output:

| ID | date | status | first_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 2022-01-03 | 1 | 2022-01-03 |
| 23 | 2022-02-03 | 1 | 2022-02-03 |

afteer this I will merge this new DF with previous DF. Final DF:

| ID | date | status | first_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 2022-01-01 | 0 | 2022-01-03 |
| 10 | 2022-01-02 | 0 | 2022-01-03 |
| 10 | 2022-01-03 | 1 | 2022-01-03 |
| 10 | 2022-01-04 | 1 | 2022-01-03 |
| 10 | 2022-01-05 | 1 | 2022-01-03 |
| 23 | 2022-02-02 | 0 | 2022-02-04 |
| 23 | 2022-02-03 | 0 | 2022-02-04 |
| 23 | 2022-02-04 | 1 | 2022-02-04 |
| 23 | 2022-02-05 | 1 | 2022-02-04 |
| 23 | 2022-02-06 | 1 | 2022-02-04 |

I tried many ways to do this, but unsuccessful

Comment: Why doesn't ID 23 have first_status as 2022-02-04?

Comment: I think it's probably a mistake, I used 2022-02-04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the first date for status=1 for each ID. Then map each ID to the first date:

```
#convert to datetime if needed
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

df["first_status"] = df["ID"].map(df[df["status"].eq(1)].groupby("ID")["date"].min())

>>> df
   ID       date  status first_status
0  10 2022-01-01       0   2022-01-03
1  10 2022-01-02       0   2022-01-03
2  10 2022-01-03       1   2022-01-03
3  10 2022-01-04       1   2022-01-03
4  10 2022-01-05       1   2022-01-03
5  23 2022-02-02       0   2022-02-04
6  23 2022-02-03       0   2022-02-04
7  23 2022-02-04       1   2022-02-04
8  23 2022-02-05       1   2022-02-04
9  23 2022-02-06       1   2022-02-04
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the status 1 rows, and get the `first` (or `min` depending on the use case) per group, then `merge` to the orginal dataframe:

```
df2 = (df[df['status'].eq(1)]
       .groupby('ID', as_index=False)
       ['date'].first() # could also use "min()"
       .rename(columns={'date': 'first_status'})
      )

df.merge(df2, on='ID')
```

output:

```
   ID        date  status first_status
0  10  2022-01-01       0   2022-01-03
1  10  2022-01-02       0   2022-01-03
2  10  2022-01-03       1   2022-01-03
3  10  2022-01-04       1   2022-01-03
4  10  2022-01-05       1   2022-01-03
5  23  2022-02-02       0   2022-02-04
6  23  2022-02-03       0   2022-02-04
7  23  2022-02-04       1   2022-02-04
8  23  2022-02-05       1   2022-02-04
9  23  2022-02-06       1   2022-02-04
```

intermediate `df2`:

```
   ID first_status
0  10   2022-01-03
1  23   2022-02-04
```